# Check for multiarch on linux/chrome OS?

Tags: linux, bash, cpu-architecture, google-chrome-os, multiarch

I'm making a hotfix for [AROC](https://github.com/nolirium/aroc) on the Chromebook Plux V2 (which has a x86_64 architecture, but no multiarch support) and I want to run a test in his script that checks for it. What command can I use to check for multiarch on a linux x86_64 system?

(Just to reference the original issue) when deploying AROC on that chromebook, the [device could not run the i686 busybox binary](https://github.com/nolirium/aroc/issues/16) that the script installs.

The author insists on the i686 binary, because the android containers that he tests deployments on are 32 bit on a host system with multiarch.

My goal is to fix his script and add support for the device I was testing on.

I plan to do this, by checking for multiarch and installing the i686 binary if a 32 bit runtime exists or installing the x86_64 binary if it doesn't. What command can I use to check for multiarch?

Answer (score 0):

you're asking about multilib support, not multiarch.

you can simply check to see if the 32-bit ldso exists: `test -e /lib/ld-linux.so.2`.